# How do i output text to a printer in c++

Tags: c++, redirect, printing

I am new to programming and seem to be having trouble figuring out how to direct output to a printer. 
cout directs to monitor, is there a command to direct to the print queue? 
I have a simple console program and am using code blocks for my ide.

Comment: what OS? I would imagine each OS has different system calls for interfacing with a printer

Answer (score 0):

A problem like this is dependent on your operating system.  Assuming you use windows, you may need to look at the 'Windows API' which may or may not have a method of doing this.  Alternatively, you can output to a text file, then use a script to open the file, run through the print menu, and close the file which is less eloquent but will work.